# Creating a scala object from java: The constructor is undefined

Tags: java, scala

I'm a novice in scala, so, sorry for a newby question :)

When I was trying to create a scala object in a Java class:

```
MyScalaObj mySo = new MyScalaObj();
```

I got error The constructor MyScalaObj() is undefined. Here is the code of MyScalaObj:

```
object MyScalaObj {
 def printSomething(something: String){
   println(something)
 }
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
    printSomething("Hello, world!")
 }
}
```

So, it seems that I should use only scala classes for such situation and I cannot create an object for java from a scala object, can I?

Thanks!

Comment: Something that is declared as an object is a singleton: there is only one of it. You can declare a class of that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bob Dalgleish said, a scala object is a singleton, so, you cannot rich its constructor.
Also, [there is useful](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/scala/singleton-and-companion-objects.html) reading for the subject.

Thanks!